# Any way to store value as struct?

Tags: swift

I have always been wondering, is it possible to store value as the struct itself.

Consider the following code:

```
struct Carplate {
   var value: String

   init (_ carplate: String) {
       value = carplate
   }

   //some other functions
}
```

In order to access the value, you would need to do:

```
let carplate = Carplate("ABC 1234")
print(carplate.value)
```

instead of:

```
print (carplate)
```

Is there any way for me to design my struct to achieve this, maybe like **repr** from python?

I see that structs in standard library are able to do this

```
let string = String("ABCDEF")
print (string)
```

is this some sort of special ability for them?

Edit:

If I would like to do this:

```
 struct Carplates {
       var value: [String]

   init (_ carplates: [String]) {
       value = carplates
   }

   //some other functions
}
```

and use it in another function:

```
let carplates = Carplates(["ABC 1234", "ABE 5678"])
if (carplates.value.count > 5) {
   // some functions
}
```

Is there any way that I can do this instead?:

```
if (carplates.count > 5) {
   // some functions
}
```

Comment: What about the other types? Like int and arrays?

Comment: Give Carplates a `count` property. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopt CustomStringConvertible.

```
   struct Carplate : CustomStringConvertible {
        var description: String { return value }
        var value: String
        init (_ carplate: String) {
            value = carplate
        }
    }
    let carplate = Carplate("ABC 1234")
    print(carplate) // ABC 1234
```

Comment: What about the other types? For example int and arrays

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible

Comment: thanks for the great answer, but from what I read at the documentation, you can only return description as a string correct? Is there ways to return other types like int or arrays?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "print" means print a string. What else could it mean?

Comment: Apologies for the poor phrasing, I mean that instead of printing, I want to use the output in another function. Is there any other protocols that allows me to return other types?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. If you want a method that expresses your struct as an array, write a method that expresses your struct as an array.

Comment: Do you mean "what would happen if `value` were an Array"???

Comment: Yes, if value happens to not be a string, maybe an array or int. Edited the question to clarify what I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172343/discussion-between-taichi-tai-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to conform to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol and write the return in `description`

```
struct Carplate : CustomStringConvertible
{
    var description: String
    {
       return value 
    }


  var value:String

    init(_ carplate:String) {

        self.value = carplate 

    }

}
```